# problem installing caret package R 3.1.5 ubuntu 18

Tags: r, r-caret, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install the caret package for R 3.5.1 in Ubuntu 18.

```
install.packages("caret", dependencies = c("Depends", "Suggests"))
```

also tried this:

```
install.packages("caret", dependencies = TRUE)
```

I get a bunch of errors like this:
[image: install output]
 I tried to install the missing dependencies one by one but it does not work. I had no problems installing some other packages. Has anyone had a similar issue? Thanks.

Comment: These error messages only tell  us that the `car` could not be installed.  The most likely reason is some missing system dependency. Basically you will have to scroll back until you see the first error message. What was the output when you tried to install e.g. `car`?

Comment: As an alternative to installing the packages from source, you can also use binary packages: https://rubuntu.netlify.com/post/2018-05-25-announcing-c2d4u3-5/

Comment: the output of the install.packages("car", dependencies=TRUE) is a bunch of similar error messages and warnings. The first error message was missing curl dependency but when trying to install those got a whole bunch of other errors. I'll try the binaries.Thanks